# How Erlang implement erlang:display actually?

Tags: erlang, interpreter, bytecode

I want to implement an Erlang interpreter and recently I'm reading about Erlang's standard library source code. I find the source code of erlang:display/1 in erlang.erl is:

```
%% display/1
-spec erlang:display(Term) -> true when
      Term :: term().
display(_Term) ->
    erlang:bif_error(undefined).
```

I don't know how it works to make a display behavior, and I think it simply throw a undefined error anyway.
By the way I've also hacked the erlang.beam to make sure the bytecode has the same semantics as the source code (erlang.erl) do.
Could anyone tell me how the erlang:display actually do?

Answer (score 5):

`erlang:display/1` is a BIF (built-in function). Some BIFs are implemented in Erlang, but most of them are implemented as primitive operations in the Erlang virtual machine since BIFs provide interfaces to the operating system or perform operations that are impossible or very inefficient to program in Erlang.

You might want to have a look to [A GUIDE TO THE ERLANG SOURCE](http://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php/A_Guide_To_The_Erlang_Source), briefly, it says;

The BIFs are summed up in the [bif.tab](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/beam/bif.tab) file. For example:

```
Line 54: bif erlang:display/1
```

means the `display/1` BIF is mapped to the `display_1` method in the [bif.c](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/beam/bif.c) file.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems erlang:display/1 is actual a bif anyway, but I still can't understand why in bytecode, the instruction for erlang:display is call_ext_only but not a bif1 or gc_bif1 (just like the add or sub bif that applied by gc_bif2), I think it makes the semantics of call_ext_only very confusing, because I think usually the call_ext_only should be used for  functions in the modules which is implemented in Erlang.